# Funcion replace

Tags: javascript

Estoy con un ejercicio en JavaScript y no entiendo el error.
Describo lo que solicita y copio como lo hago

Nuestra misión, ahora, es crear una función llamada `reemplazoFastFast` que va a recibir los siguientes tres parámetros:

1. Un texto.
2. La palabra que vamos a buscar para reemplazar.
3. La palabra que vamos a usar para reemplazar.

La función deberá devolver el texto con la palabra reemplazada.

Esto es lo que intente!

```
function reemplazoFastFast (texto,buscar,usar){
  let reemplazoFastFast= ('El viernes comemos carne','carne','verduras')
  console.log(reemplazoFastFast.replace ('mala','buena'))
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado?

Comment: puedes pulsar [edit] para agregar a la pregunta el código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que no estás comprendiendo bien cómo funciona una función, la función has de declararla y después invocarla, dentro de ella realizar lo que quieras con los parámetros.

```js
/*Declaramos la función con sus parámetros*/
function reemplazoFastFast (texto,buscar,usar){
  //realizamos el replace con los parametros
  return texto.replace(buscar,usar);
}
/*Invocamos la función y le pasamos los tres parametros*/
console.log(reemplazoFastFast("JavaScript no me permite aprender", "no", "si"));
```